# Trim extra characters from dateTime difference

Tags: xslt

Hope you are doing fine.
I have a scenario where I've to calculate the difference between a dateTime field and the current date. I could calculate the difference, but only in dateTime format.

I've used this xslt to calculate the diff b/w days

```
<xsl:call-template name="timeDifference">
          <xsl:with-param name="date1"
                          select="$PrjOwnerFinishDate_OutputVar.result/ns1:SummaryPlannedFinishDate"/><!--input var-->
          <xsl:with-param name="date2" select="xp20:current-dateTime()"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
```

---

```
<xsl:template name="timeDifference">
    <xsl:param name="date1"/>
    <xsl:param name="date2"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="xsd:dateTime($date1) - xsd:dateTime($date2)"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

This is returning the difference, but in this format :: `-P26DT23H51M40S or P5DT8M20S`

But I want only the days in there(like -26 or 5 in the above examples), including '+'/'-' sign. i.e. `Trim 'P'` and everything after `'D'`

How do I do that?

`day-from-dateTime()` is not working. Would you please help me in this regard.

Regards
RaviKiran

Answer (score 0):

Familiarize yourself with the functions offered on extracting components from durations (which you have after substracting two dateTime values): http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#component-extraction-functions, like http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-days-from-duration.